# Does the Nintendo New 2DS XL feature improved processing power compared to the old 3DS (XL)?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

Does the Nintendo New 2DS XL feature improved processing power compared to the old 3DS (XL)? By "processing power" I mean CPU/GPU speed and available memory.

I'm asking this because I have the Metal Gear Solid: Snake Eater 3D, but on the (old) 3DS XL it lags incredibly during CQC and pretty much any action.

Answer (score 3):

It does.
In order to be able to play *New* 3DS enhanced software it has more processing power than a regular 3DS. That includes [better CPU and more memory](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2017/06/hardware_review_new_nintendo_2ds_xl). Except for the lack of 3D feature, it has all the enhancements of the New 3DS compared to the old 2DS/3DS.

You can check the features comparison [on Nintendo's website](https://www.nintendo.com/3ds/features/compare).